# How to get all instances of dataTables on page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, responsive

I have a webpage on which I have multiple dataTables, using the latest https://datatables.net/.

html code:

```
<div id="collapse{{ $oCategory->id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Current Inventory</th>
                                <th>Minimum Inventory</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            @foreach ($oProducts->where('iCategoryId', $oCategory->id) as $i=>$oProduct)

                                <tr class="{{ (($i % 2) == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd' }}">
                                    <td>{{ $oProduct->sName }}</td>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-euro"></i> {{ $oProduct->fPrice }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $oProduct->getInventory() }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $oProduct->getMinimumInventory() }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="/inventory/product/{{$oProduct->id}}/edit"><i class="fa fa-edit text-primary"></i></a>
                                        <a href="/inventory/product/{{$oProduct->id}}/delete"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle text-danger"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            @endforeach


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a href="/inventory/category/{{$oCategory->id}}/product"><button class="btn btn-success">Add product</button></a>
                                {{--<button class="btn btn-success" id="addRow" onclick="addTableRow();">Add product</button>--}}
                                {{--<button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveButton" onclick="saveRow();" style="display: none;">Save</button>--}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                                <a href="/inventory/category/{{$oCategory->id}}/edit"><button class="btn btn-warning">Edit category</button></a>
                                <a href="/inventory/category/{{$oCategory->id}}/delete"><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete category</button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I read in the docs that in order to initialize all the tables on my page I can just create call DataTable() on a jquery array and all the tables will get instanced. This works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table-striped').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
  });

  $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function (e) {
    setTimeout(reCalc, 200);
  });

  reCalc = function() {
    console.log($.fn.dataTable.tables());
    $.fn.dataTable.tables( { api: true } ).columns.adjust();
  }
})
```

However, all my tables are inside bootstraps collapsibles, meaning the datatable cannot figure out the width at the time of creation when the collapse is closed. Therefore I am calling my function reCalc() (see code).

However, the weird thing is that $.fn.dataTable.tables() only returns the last table on the page, and therefore only the last table is responsive. I would expect it to return all tables (see the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.tables())).

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please try and post a (minimal) executable sample. You can include Bootstrap and DataTables and anything else you need in a StackOverflow snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this page in the official doc can help:https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.tables()

```
$.fn.dataTable
    .tables( { visible: true, api: true } )
    .columns.adjust();

//example 2

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $.fn.dataTable
            .tables( { visible: true, api: true } )
            .columns.adjust();
    })
```